# ложиться бот на хероку

Tags: python, git, aiogram, heroku

Написал телеграм бота на пайтоне с деплоем на хероку, но из-за неизвестной мне причине он ставит статус crash, а не up

**bot.py**

```
import asyncio
import logging

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from config import BOT_TOKEN
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from aiogram import types
import random

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

async def main():

    logging.basicConfig(
        level = logging.INFO,
        format = u'%(filename)s:%(lineno)d #%(levelname)-8s [%(asctime)s] - %(name)s - %(message)s'
    )
    
    
    logger.info("Starting bot")

    bot = Bot(token=BOT_TOKEN, parse_mode="HTML")
    storage = MemoryStorage()
    dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)

    with open("Compliment_Bot/complimets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        compliments = f.readlines()

    @dp.message_handler(content_types=(types.ContentTypes.PHOTO | types.ContentTypes.VIDEO | types.ContentTypes.VIDEO_NOTE))
    async def compliment(message: types.Message):
        await bot.send_message(
            message.from_user.id,
            text=random.choice(compliments),
        )
        

    try: 
        await dp.start_polling()
    finally:
        await dp.storage.close()
        await dp.storage.wait_closed()
        await bot.session.close()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        asyncio.run(main())
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        logger.error("Bot stopped!")
```

**requirements.txt**

```
aiogram==2.20
aiohttp==3.8.1
aiosignal==1.2.0
APScheduler==3.6.3
asgiref==3.5.2
async-timeout==4.0.2
asyncio==3.4.3
attrs==21.4.0
Babel==2.9.1
cachetools==4.2.2
certifi==2021.10.8
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
configparser==5.2.0
Django==4.0.4
frozenlist==1.3.0
idna==3.3
magic-filter==1.0.7
multidict==6.0.2
pydantic==1.9.1
Pygments==2.12.0
python-telegram-bot==13.11
pytz==2022.1
pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0
six==1.16.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
telegram==0.0.1
telegramApi==1.5
tornado==6.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
tzdata==2022.1
tzlocal==4.2
yarl==1.7.2
```

**runtime.txt**

`python-3.10.4`

**Procfile**

`worker: python bot.py`

**Логи Herocu:**

```
2022-07-24T20:46:30.866988+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-07-24T20:46:30.876693+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-07-24T20:46:36.040469+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `python bot.py`
2022-07-24T20:46:36.652200+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-07-24T20:46:37.344229+00:00 app[worker.1]: bot.py:21 #INFO     [2022-07-24 20:46:37,344] - __main__ - Starting bot
2022-07-24T20:46:37.352943+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2022-07-24T20:46:37.352950+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/bot.py", line 49, in <module>
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353033+00:00 app[worker.1]: asyncio.run(main())
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353042+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353110+00:00 app[worker.1]: return loop.run_until_complete(main)
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353118+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353273+00:00 app[worker.1]: return future.result()
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353283+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/bot.py", line 27, in main
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353335+00:00 app[worker.1]: with open("Compliment_Bot\complimets.txt", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
2022-07-24T20:46:37.353358+00:00 app[worker.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Compliment_Bot\\complimets.txt'
2022-07-24T20:46:37.508075+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-24T20:46:37.623719+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

Подключал хероку через гит

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Compliment_Bot\\complimets.txt'`

Comment: если локально все работало, то подозреваю что пишите Вы на `Windows`, но на heroku `Linux` и путь к файлу должен быть иным "Compliment_Bot/complimets.txt" (не через обратную косую) чтобы об этом никогда не задумываться нужно пользоваться функциями конкатенации путей `os.path.join` к примеру

Comment: есть какие-нибудь статьи по этому поводу?\